# how do I use the CSS hover on only SOME cells in a table?

Tags: html, css

How do I use the CSS hover on only SOME cells in a table?
Can I turn it off on those that I don't want it applied to?
I'm using this:

```
td:hover {
    border-style:dotted;
    border-color:#F60;
    border-width:medium;
    border-left-style:dotted;
    border-right-style:dotted;

}
```

But I need it to only apply to certain cells

Comment: Does this 'some cells' have a pattern or just random cells?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of specifying your style for all cells you can create a class and only apply that to the cells you want the style on. Update your css to this:

```
.myclass:hover {
    border-style:dotted;
    border-color:#F60;
    border-width:medium;
    border-left-style:dotted;
    border-right-style:dotted;

}
```

Then you do something like this in the HTML code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="myclass">Cell 1 with special hoover</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>     
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `<td>` tag supports Global Attributes in HTML so you can simply add a class to your code for each of the table cells you want to have the hover on.

```
...
<td class="cell-hover">Table Cell Data</td>
...
```

The modify your CSS Selector to include the selection of only td cells that have the "cell-hover" class.

```
td:hover {
   border-style:dotted;
   border-color:#F60;
   border-width:medium;
   border-left-style:dotted;
   border-right-style:dotted;
}
```

By using a `.` within CSS you can select only the elements that have the proceeding class name

Comment: @honeycomb13 please accept the answer if it solved your problem and possibly upvote it as well.