# CSS hover on a table row with the exception of some cells

Tags: html, css, hover

Based on my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647186/css-hover-not-works-on-a-table-cell-if-it-has-a-specific-background-color/61750429#61750429) I would like to add a 4th column, that contains only images. The hover should not effect this column. Because of the image is smaller, then the cell itself, it looks strange with hover. I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585179/how-do-i-use-the-css-hover-on-only-some-cells-in-a-table), but for this to work, I had to mark every `<td>` with a class attribute EXCEPT the 4th `<td>` of each row. But the table in the code below has a different structure: only the columns, that have a special meaning, have a class attribute. In this case the 4th `<td>` of each row has the class `rightTD`.

I did the following modifications on the CSS:

```
.multidata tbody>tr:hover td:not(.rightTD) {
  background-color: #96c7ef!important;
}
```

(Added `:not(.rightTD)`)

The HTML was extended with a new header:

```
<th style="width: 10%">Button</th>
```

and the two cells having the same content:

```
<td class="rightTD" align="center">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZiS0dEAIcApgBpEx4v0wAAAAlwSFlzAAAN1wAADdcBQiibeAAAAAd0SU1FB9sMBw0pJeuQSwsAAAEJSURBVDjL3ZQ9TsNAEIU/I18k93CHUOSGSCA3VhqofIK0EW1OEFFBgyKlIaJI4YYi9+AgeN5QmEX5E94oLhDTrXbmzZv3Zhf+eiRdCfN6wnqzBCDPCqqr2a/5aURTP4VEJ+B6s+S+rDCJ58VjZ/eLGF0kx82jNIwZGTMhKQowiqHLcZ3IcF5PADw4uh3NZ4O+AUfTwQ5ynhUASXA/3RYf4K6skITMkQlr9HO+HY5pGmEmXEJy9gmkh+MJNyG1ZgQwlzC1TQLYMV3TPeo8HVmNm+EYSbzWLwd3oW7FLO6ljKYDv74scRNv7wtWDx/J+S73vTZBx/4WW60pvQDmWbHz2wTxz2GY8K/iC8BCorjCvk26AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
</td>
```

The problem: the 4th column (except the header) is still effected by the hover.

How can i disable the hover on 4th column ?

Below is the code:

```css
.multidata td,.multidata th {
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

.multidata tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color:#96c7ef!important;
}

.multidata  tbody>tr:hover td:not(.rightTD) {
    background-color:#96c7ef!important;
}

.tdX {
    background-color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.tdY {
    background-color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./basic.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<table class="multidata" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="change_on_hover">
            <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Status</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Button</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr class="change_on_hover">
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>1</i></td>
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>First</i></td>
        <td class="tdX" align="center"><b>Disabled</b></td>
        <td class="rightTD" align="center"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="change_on_hover">
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>2</i></td>
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>Second</i></td>
        <td class="tdY" align="center"><b>Active</b></td>
        <td class="rightTD" align="center"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best not to use `!important` in css whenever possible, it becomes a challenge to override it afterward. Rather than applying the hover on the `<TR>` it was moved to the `<TD>` and the `:last-of-type` selector was used to keep the fourth `<TD>` background transparent.

```css
.multidata td,
.multidata th {
  border: 2px solid #808080;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.multidata tbody>tr:hover td {
  background-color: #96c7ef;
}

.multidata tbody>tr:hover td:last-of-type {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.tdX {
  background-color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tdY {
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./basic.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="multidata" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
      <tr class="change_on_hover">
        <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Name</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Status</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Button</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr class="change_on_hover">
      <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>1</i></td>
      <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>First</i></td>
      <td class="tdX" align="center"><b>Disabled</b></td>
      <td class="rightTD" align="center"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
        /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="change_on_hover">
      <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>2</i></td>
      <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>Second</i></td>
      <td class="tdY" align="center"><b>Active</b></td>
      <td class="rightTD" align="center"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
        /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanx, it helpd a lot. You're right with !important, but in my case the HTML is rendered on the server side, and if some condition is true, then an inline style (a background color or font setting) is added to the <TD>. I use !important, to "overwrite" these ruels. I use  "td.rightTD"  instead of  "td:last-of-type", because if the last column doesn't have this class attribute, then this CSS rule should also not apply. But anyway thanx for the hint :-)

Comment: I have a question to the rule:  ".multidata tbody>tr:hover td  {background-color:green}". Does this mean, you apply the hover on the <TR> by setting the color of each <TD> of the current <TR> ? Why can't we just write:  ".multidata tbody>tr td:hover  {background-color:green}"  ?  Practically we have to select each <TD> of the current <TR> and apply a style for all of them, right ?

Comment: 1) You are correct. When a table row is hovered over, apply a background color to all the columns within it. 2) That css rule is saying to apply a hover only on one column at a time. 3) That's right, style all the columns, but change it for particular instances. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
.multidata tbody>tr:hover td:not(:last-child) {
    background-color:#96c7ef!important;
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation for your code would be preferred